# Сокращение кода в JS. Стоит ли?

Tags: javascript

Случайно наткнулся на интересное сокращение в JS. Для создания объекта с функциями, я использовал такой фрагмент кода:

```
var a = {
   func1: function(){

   },
   func2: function(){

   }
};
```

Как-то случайно я написал таким образом:

```
var a = {
   func1(){

   },
   func2(){

   }
};
```

Что первый, что второй вариант по функциям - одинаковый(ИМХО).
Вопрос: Давно ли такое сокращение работает( Есть подозрения, что пришло от ECMA 6)? Стоит ли так сокращать? Есть какие-то недостатки такого способа?

Comment: нечитаемо скорее всего, не проще потом минифицировать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Данная возможность добавлена в [ECMA2015](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-method-definitions).

В дополнение к геттерам и сеттерам, в инициализаторе объекта теперь можно объявлять методы и генераторы.

> MethodDefinition<sub>[Yield]</sub> :
>               *PropertyName*<sub>[?Yield]</sub> ( StrictFormalParameters ) { FunctionBody }
>               GeneratorMethod<sub>[?Yield]</sub>
>               **get** PropertyName<sub>[?Yield]</sub> ( ) { FunctionBody }
>               **set** PropertyName<sub>[?Yield]</sub> ( PropertySetParameterList ) { FunctionBody }

Разницы с предыдущей записью нет, поэтому можно использовать любую форму, и даже все вместе.

Comment: а на сколько этот метод кроссбраузерный?

Comment: @Node_pro, из популярных браузеров [поддерживают все кроме IE](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-object_literal_extensions_shorthand_methods)

Comment: благодарю! Вот как раз нашел сайт https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: @Node_pro, в моем комментарии как раз на этот сайт ссылка.

Comment: пардон не увидел

Answer (score -1):

Используйте реальные классы, которые появились в новом стандарте.

- [JavaScript classes](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-class#class)

Также советую вам попробовать TypeScript, который может тоже самое, что и Javascript, и даже больше. При этом его можно конвертировать в обычный JavaScript.

- [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/)

Comment: Меня смущает поддержка браузерами. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Да, с поддержкой все плохо, но всегда можно воспользоваться трансляцией в старый синтаксис, например, с помощью Babel (https://babeljs.io/)